# Problems with multiple dropzone instances

Tags: dropzone.js

I try to insert two dropzones (http://www.dropzonejs.com/), but I always get "Uncaught Error: Dropzone already attached."

Here is my Code. Can anybody help me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $("#DropzoneTarget_1").dropzone({url: "...."});
    $("#DropzoneTarget_2").dropzone({url: "...."});
});
```

Thanx and greeds

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue if running the same code multiple times.
Prevent this error by destroying the Dropzone object instance, so only 1 instance exists at a time.

```
if (myDropzone1 != undefined) {
    Dropzone.forElement("#DropzoneTarget_1").destroy();
}

var myDropzone1 = $("#DropzoneTarget_1").dropzone({url: "...."});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have 'dropzone' class on yours '#DropzoneTarget_1' and '#DropzoneTarget_2'. Remove it and your code will work.

If you need default styles just config yours dropzones with

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneTarget1 = {/*option:value*/}
Dropzone.options.dropzoneTarget2 = {/*option:value*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "dropzone" class didn´t work, but this solved my problem

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $(".dropzone").each(function () {
        new Dropzone($(this).get(0), {url: "...."});
    });
  });
```

Thanks for your help.