# dropzone attach only on the first element in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dropzone.js

Hello I am trying to make list where against every record it has a box, where you can drag`n drop files. I am using VUEjs and when apply v-for it works only the first one.

Here is my code -> https://github.com/iliyan940/euromedic_v2/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/cases.vue

Comment: Please don't simply provide a link to your code, include your relevant code in the post itself

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No but it seems like only the first item is recognized and have dz-clickable class attached and the others do not.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

[Problems with multiple dropzone instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178296/problems-with-multiple-dropzone-instances/28361563#28361563)

This code was the key.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$(".dropzone").each(function () {
    new Dropzone($(this).get(0), {url: "...."});
});
```

});